# Test Class for a void method

Tags: apex, unit-test

```
public class Main{
     public class Sub{
         public List<case> caseList = new List<Case>();
     }
     public void caseInsert(List<case> caseL){
     Sub f = new Sub();
       for(Case c : caseL){
          if(c.status == 'Closed'){
             f.caseList.add(c);
          }
       }
     }
}
```

Test Method:

```
@isTest
public static void testmethod1(){
   Main m = new Main();
   Main.Sub s = new Main.Sub();
   List<Case> testCases = ;//test data to create 10 cases out of which 4 are closed => 
   m.caseInsert(testCases);
   system.assertEquals(6, s.caseList.size())
}
```

Assertion always fails and shows s.caseList.size() as zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a separate instance of Main.Sub with a variable of F in your class....

Change to:

```
public class Main{
     public Sub f;
     private class Sub{
         public List<case> caseList = new List<Case>();
     }
     public void caseInsert(List<case> caseL){
       f = new Sub();
       for(Case c : caseL){
          if(c.status == 'Closed'){
             f.caseList.add(c);
          }
       }
     }
}
```

then change you assert to

```
system.assertEquals(6, m.f.caseList.size())
```